# Marcar registros en una tabla

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hola Buenas tardes estoy intentando poner de color rojo los registros de mi tabla que se muestren repetidos, pero los unicos ejemplos que encuentro ocupan un DataGridView y no se como poder hacerlo con mi codigo que es mvc y de tres capas. Espero me puedan orientar , esto es lo que llevo.

entrfc ; es donde estan los datos de mi tabla

```
public class EntRFC
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombres { get; set; }
        public string Paterno { get; set; }
        public string Materno { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaNacimiento { get; set; }

        public string Rfc { get; set; }
```

DatRfc es donde se encuentra mi consulta de datos repetidos en sql server

```
public DataTable NombreRepetido(string Nombres, string Paterno, string Materno)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spNombreRepetido", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombres", Nombres);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Paterno", Paterno);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Materno", Materno);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
```

mi BusRfc es donde deberia ser la condicion que me marcaria los datos en rojo pero no se como hacerla del todo.

```
public void ValidarNombre(EntRFC p)
        {
            
            DataTable existe = objConexion.NombreRepetido(p.Nombres, p.Paterno, p.Materno);
            if(existe.Rows.Count >0)
            {
                List<EntRFC>.Rows[existe].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                //EntRFC.Rows[existe].Style.BackColor = Color.Blue;

            }
        }
```

tengo mi vista que se llama ObtenerRegistros ahi se muestran mis registros, en mi HomeController solo pongo esto

```
     public ActionResult ObtenerRegistros()
            {
                
                return View(new BusRFC().Obtener());
            }
y la vista viene esto
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr class="btn-dark" style="background-color:black; color:white;">
        <th>
            Nombre
        </th>
        <th>
            Fecha de Nacimiento
        </th>
        <th>
            Rfc
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NombreCompleto)
            </td>
         </tr>
```

Igual en mi BusRfc para mostrar los datos en la tabla ocupe una lista

```
public class BusRFC
    {
        DatRFC objConexion = new DatRFC();
        public List<EntRFC> Obtener()
        {
            DataTable dt = objConexion.Obtener();
            List<EntRFC> list = new List<EntRFC>();
            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                EntRFC p = new EntRFC();
                p.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Id"]);
                p.Nombres = dr["Nombres"].ToString();
                p.Paterno = dr["Paterno"].ToString();
                p.Materno = dr["Materno"].ToString();
                p.FechaNacimiento = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["FechaNacimiento"]);
                p.Rfc = dr["Rfc"].ToString();
                
                list.Add(p);
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Comment: Que es lo que te retorna `NombreRepetido`?  Es decir, que te retorna `spNombreRepetido`?

Comment: Mi consulta en proc almacenado : select * from registros where Nombres=@Nombres and Paterno=@Paterno and Materno=@Materno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te paso una idea para que puedas avanzar aplicándole la lógica que más te convenga. Tené en cuenta que es muy mejorable todo. Mi intención es que arranques con algo, que a veces es lo más difícil.

Para comenzar, extendamos la entidad **EntRFC** con un campo más, para marcarla como "repetida o no repetida". Para esto, tan solo agregarías una nueva propiedad booleana:

```
public class EntRFC
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nombres { get; set; }
        public string Paterno { get; set; }
        public string Materno { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaNacimiento { get; set; }

        public string Rfc { get; set; }
        
        public bool Repetido { get; set; }
    }
```

A continuación, obtenemos la lista de personas de la base de datos, tal como lo hiciste hasta ahora, solo que como vamos a manipularla antes de pasarla a la vista, esta vez la guardamos en una variable, para luego pasarlo por un método que te marque las entidades repetidas.

En resumen, sería algo similar a lo siguiente:

```
public ActionResult ObtenerRegistros()
{
    BusRFC busRFC = new BusRFC();
    List<EntRFC> listaPersonas = busRFC.Obtener();
    busRFC.MarcarNombresDuplicados(ref listaPersonas);
    return View(listaPersonas);
}
```

Y este sería el detalle del método **MarcarNombresDuplicados()** (lo declaré en la clase **busRFC**, pero sentite libre de crearlo donde te convenga):

```
public void MarcarNombresDuplicados(ref List<EntRFC> listaPersonas)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < listaPersonas.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < listaPersonas.Count; j++)
        {
            if(listaPersonas[i].Nombres == listaPersonas[j].Nombres &&
               listaPersonas[i].Paterno == listaPersonas[j].Paterno &&
               listaPersonas[i].Materno == listaPersonas[j].Materno)
            {
                listaPersonas[i].Repetido = true;
                listaPersonas[j].Repetido = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tené en cuenta que en el método anterior, no se vuelve a consultar a la base de datos para obtener los repetidos como en el código original (no lo encontré necesario), sino que utiliza la misma lista que obtuviste en un principio. Si aún así necesitás obtenerlo de la base de datos, solo habría que realizar algunas pequeñas modificaciones.

Con esto, ya estarías enviando a la vista un listado de personas, cada una con su estado de "repetido". Ahora solo resta aplicar el formato correspondiente:

```
@{
    @model List<Models.EntRFC>;
}
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr class="btn-dark" style="background-color:black; color:white;">
        <th>Nombre completo</th>
        <th>Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
        <th>Rfc</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr @(item.Repetido ? "style=background-color:red" : "")>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombres) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Paterno) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Materno)</td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FechaNacimiento) </td>
            <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rfc) </td>
        </tr>
    }
 </table>
```

Resultando en algo similar a lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente que se ve todo feo, sin formato, pero bueno, eso es lo de menos.

Espero que te haya servido lo que te pasé, y si no se entiende algo, avisame.

Saludos.

Comment: si , me quedo muchas gracias por la ayuda , :3 se lo agradezco bastante